# Symbols showing up on urxvt with agnoster

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, rxvt

I just started using and customising urxvt and it turns out that my agnoster theme for oh-my-zsh produces symbols/text in place of where the arrows should be. Here are some screenshots:

[urxvt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN70C.png)

[terminator (another terminal)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onSU8.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a powerline enabled font. For example to set [Inconsolata for Powerline](https://github.com/powerline/fonts/tree/master/Inconsolata) as your font, install the font and edit your `~/.Xdefaults` file and set

```
urxvt*font: xft:Terminus:size=12,xft:Inconsolata\ for\ Powerline:size=12
```

This will make urxvt use the `Terminus` font by default but fall back to `Inconsolata for Powerline` for characters not in `Terminus`, such as the arrows, large angle brackets, VCS characters etc.

Check out the [powerline documentation](http://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/master/tips-and-tricks.html) for more tips.

Comment: It still does not work sadly. Here is my `~/.Xresources` file : http://pastebin.com/rZSXerYN (I am running Arch GNU/Linux)

Comment: You need a powerline-enabled font. E.g. install [Inconsolata For Powerline](https://github.com/powerline/fonts/tree/master/Inconsolata), replace [line 70 of your ~/.Xresources](http://pastebin.com/F6bkc4SE), with `URxvt*font: xft:Inconsolata\ For\ Powerline:size=11` to test. Close rxvt-unicode, merge the resources (`xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` and re-open rxvt-unicode.

Comment: Play with the font, try leaving off the `:size=11` part or change to `:size=13`. Getting the URxvt font right means trial and error. Also check out examples from the Arch Linux Forums.